# Selecting the most recent row by timestamp for multiple entries while joining another table with substring of the current one

Tags: sql, oracle, select, join, substr

Ok, the title sounds awfully complicated, but what I actually want to do is not that complex. My tables are:

Servicestatustable:

```
ServiceIdentifier           ServiceStatus   Timestamp

System1-Service1            1               sometimestamp
System1-Service1            1               sometimestamp
System2-Service1            0               sometimestamp
System2-Service1            1               sometimestamp
System1-Service2            1               sometimestamp
System1-Service2            0               sometimestamp
System2-Service2            1               sometimestamp
System2-Service2            1               sometimestamp
System3-Service42           0               sometimestamp
```

Systemnametable:

```
SystemIdentifier   SystemName

System1            Baconsystem
System2            LoremIpsumSystem
System3            System42
```

Desired Output:

```
Baconsystem, Service1, 1, sometimestamp
Baconsystem, Service2, 1, sometimestamp
LoremIpsumSystem, Service1, 1, sometimestamp
LoremIpsumSystem, Service2, 1, sometimestamp
System42, Service42, 0, sometimestamp
```

The SQL Query (Oracle) should only output the most recent entry for each system-service combination, according to the timestamp. I just can't get the join over the substring to work properly when combined with trying to get every system-service combination to be output only once. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use `MAX` in subquery. Or, use analytic `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY timestamp DESC`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of possibilities is solution with functions substr(), instr(), row_number():

```
select sn, sv, sst, st 
  from (
    with st as (
      select 
          substr(ServiceIdentifier, 1, instr(ServiceIdentifier, '-')-1) syst,
          substr(ServiceIdentifier, instr(ServiceIdentifier, '-')+1) service, 
          ServiceStatusTable.*
        from ServiceStatusTable)
    select sn.systemname sn, st.service sv, st.servicestatus sst, st.servicetime st,
        row_number() over (partition by systemname, service 
          order by st.servicetime desc) rn
      from st join Systemnametable sn on st.syst = sn.systemidentifier )
  where rn = 1
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4ebc0/1)

Answer (score 1):

One method of doing this takes advantage of Oracle regular expressions:

```
select snt.systemname, sst.service, sst.servicestatus, sst.timestamp
from (select sst.*,
             regexp_substr(ServiceIdentifier, '[^-]+', 1, 1) as system,
             regexp_substr(ServiceIdentifier, '[^-]+', 1, 2) as service,
             row_number() over (partition by ServiceIdentifier
                                order by timestamp desc) as seqnum
      from Servicestatustable sst
     ) sst left join
     Systemnametable snt
     on snt.SystemIdentifier = sst.system
where seqnum = 1;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4ebc0/5) is the SQL Fiddle for this version (thanks to Ponder for creating it).